# What is the role of visibility filter in colections Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, order-items, visibility

I am getting Order Items, from order collection by Order ID but as from the attached screen shot (Order 15) I am getting one product data two times. Can any body explain the reason and what will be its solution as I need it once.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Sparta Gym Tank** is configurable product. Check **parent_item_id** for this item. If **parent_item_id** is not empty/null then this product is child product.

**parent_item_id** is the parent configurable product